# How to modify an hexadecimal string bytes by bytes in Python?

Tags: python, hex

I'm programming a little piece of code to swap headers between .bmp and .wav files. I managed to extract raw bytes (e.g. `\x00\x12`) and transform it into a string (`0012`) but what I wanna do now is split the string in a way that I can modify it two bytes by two bytes.
This means that I have my hex string, for example `FACB3D52`, and I want it to be split out `FACB` so that I can apply rules in it (if there is A, replace by B), and then it moves forward to `3D52`, apply the same rules, and reassemble the string so that it outputs `FBCB3D52`

I do not have much experience in Python and I really have no clues on how I should go for this problem

Answer (score 0):

If you are applying the same rule to each chunk of the hexadecimal number, you can use the following.

```
hexstr = "FACB3D52"

hexlist = [hexstr[i:i+4] for i in range(len(hexstr)//4)] # Split into list of substrings
new_hexlist = [substr.replace('A', 'B') for substr in hexlist] # Apply rule to each substring
new_hexstr = ''.join(new_hexlist) # Join substrings back to form final string

print(new_hexstr)
```

**Output**

> FBCBBCB3